# XSLT: How to replace the first sibling with a concatenation of all siblings?

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I'm having a hard time trying to implement an XSL transformation.

I need to transform this:

```
<records>
    <item>
        <id type="uid">1</id>
        <name>Homepage</name>
        <attr>AB308E</attr>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id type="uid">5</id>
        <name>Electronics</name>
        <attr>F04550</attr>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id type="uid">8</id>
        <name>Accessories</name>
        <attr>00EE80</attr>
    </item>
</records>
```

into this:

```
<records>
    <item>
        <id type="uid">1</id>
        <category>Homepage - Electronics - Accessories</category>
        <attr>AB308E</attr>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id type="uid">5</id>
        <name>Electronics</name>
        <attr>F04550</attr>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id type="uid">8</id>
        <name>Accessories</name>
        <attr>00EE80</attr>
    </item>
</records>
```

I know it doesn't make a lot of sense semantically speaking, but that's a hack I need in order to inject data in a specific manner into some interface.

Rule #1: the `name` tag of the first `item` of each `records` tag (there are many records in the actual file) turns into `category` and contains the concatenation of all item's names from the current `records` scope

Rule #2: `item` tags that are not first child of `records` are unchanged.

I tried using `<xsl:value-of select="concat(' - ', .)"/>` rules but had no luck.

Would anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Use `<xsl:value-of select="., ../following-sibling::item/name" separator=" - "/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="records/item[1]/name">
        <category>        
            <xsl:for-each select="../../item/name">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="' - '" />
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </category>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the identity transformation as the base template and add a template

```
  <xsl:template match="records/item[1]/name">
      <category>
          <xsl:value-of select="., ../following-sibling::item/name" separator=" - "/>
      </category>
  </xsl:template>
```